# Parsing HTML using Microsoft.mshtml

Tags: c#, html, mshtml

So I am attempting to parse some small amounts of html using `mshtml`.  However I am having some problems.  I need to get the get the `innerHtml` out of an `IHtmlElement`.  First, I create an `IHtmlDocument2` object and grab the main span tag I call root (wraps around everything) like shown below.

```
 string html = someHtml;
 object[] objects = { html };
 mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
 mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)doc;
 doc2.write(objects);
 mshtml.IHTMLElement root = doc.getElementById("root");
```

I will then pump through the children of "root" and do something with the innerHtml like so.

```
foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement e in  (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)root.children)
{
    someString = e.innerHtml.substring(0, 1);
    //or something similar  
}
```

This works fine.  However, I run into problems when the elements `innerHtml` contains an `<ol>`, `<ul>` or any self closing tag such as `<br/>`.  The issue I am having is when the innerHtml of an html tag contains one of these, the `innerHTML` in the `IHtmlElement` object doesn't get set, and remains null.  Is there a way around this? I find it hard to believe that mshtml cannot handle these types of basic html tags.  Therefore I feel like I am doing something wrong.  Your ideas, comments and feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: tried to load via IPersistFile or IPersistStreamInit?

Comment: Negative. This the first I have heard of these interfaces, so I don't know or how they work.  I was able to build a workaround for the select cases that I am using it for, but it is not an ideal situation.

Comment: I don't think either of these would apply in my situation.  The HTML code I am parsing is not coming from a file or a stream.  It is being stored in a database.  It is then retrieved as a string object prior to parsing.

Comment: you can create a stream from memory see SHCreateMemStream